Installed latest version of highcharts 11.4.7 getting error in finding enum XAxisType.Datetime
In the UI we are using XAxisType.Datetime
 highChart.Series = highChart.AddLineChartSctterLineSeries(InputData);
                        highChart.XAxis[0].Type = XAxisType.Datetime;
                        highChart.XAxis[0].Min = 0;
                        highChart.XAxis[0].Max = 10;


While trying to set XAxis[0].Type we are getting error. Not able to find the replacement for this one. How do we find the replacement for this in the DLL?
Configure the XAxisType may be got renamed or changed to single type for both x-axis and y-axis.
After installing hte latest highcharts DLL MinorGridLineDashStyle  is accepting on Hashtable but when coming into script it is giving error
public Hashtable MinorGridLineDashStyle { get; set; }

"jQuery.Deferred exception: t.toLowerCase is not a function", "TypeError: t.toLowerCase is not a function
    at I.dashstyleSetter (https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js:8:37363)
    at I.&lt;anonymous&gt; (https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js:8:35183)
    at C (https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js:8:1553)
    at I.attr (https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js:8:34975)
    at Object.renderGridLine (https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js:8:76562)
    at Object.render (https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js:8:76026)
    at N.renderMinorTick (https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js:8:101747)
    at https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js:8:102632
    at Array.forEach (&lt;anonymous&gt;)
    at N.render (https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js:8:102610)", undefined

And from UI when tried manually modifiying and putting the below block it is working
"minorGridLineDashStyle" : "Dot"

Is there any workaround for this issue or am i doing something wrong.
Thanks in advance!!

Hi @Anju Raman, This is a bug in Highcharts .NET integration. It is already reported and should be fixed in the near future. As a workaround, you should be able to set the proper string value: xAxisType = "datetime".

Thanks @ppotaczek that worked. But with dashstyle i am facing similar issue.
"minorGridLineDashStyle":{"DashStyle":"Dot"}, This property is accepting only hashtable from .NET C# but its throwing error in script side. Any work around for this issue.

is there any workaround for this issue?

Check the related thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78958683/after-highcharts-upgrade-to-latest-version-getting-error-in-setting-dashstyle-pr#comment139227824_78958683

can you give me an example. Is it through JS we have to set this custom field ?
