After highcharts upgrade to latest version getting error in setting dashstyle property in xaxis
After installing hte latest highcharts DLL MinorGridLineDashStyle  is accepting on Hashtable but when coming into script it is giving error
public Hashtable MinorGridLineDashStyle { get; set; }

And from UI when tried manually modifiying and putting the below block it is working
"minorGridLineDashStyle" : "Dot"

Now the issue is we cannot handle it from C#. Is there any workaround for this issue or am i doing something wrong.
Expecting to load line chart
    at I.dashstyleSetter (https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js:8:37363)
    at I.&lt;anonymous&gt; (https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js:8:35183)
    at C (https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js:8:1553)
    at I.attr (https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js:8:34975)
    at Object.renderGridLine (https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js:8:76562)
    at Object.render (https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js:8:76026)
    at N.renderMinorTick (https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js:8:101747)
    at https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js:8:102632
    at Array.forEach (&lt;anonymous&gt;)
    at N.render (https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js:8:102610)", undefined


Hi, what wrapper do you use, is it official Highcharts .NET Standard Wrapper or DotNet.Highcharts?

This seems to be a bug. As a workaround, you need to use CustomFields. The key must be the name of the property in JavaScript, and the value must be a string.

i did not understand this one. Is it like we cannot set value for
highChart.XAxis[0].GridLineDashStyle = ""; ? Then if custom field can you give me an example how to do the same.

Try out: xAxis.CustomFields = new Hashtable() { { "minorGidLineDashStyle", "Dash" } };
