Highchart not working with latest DLL in .Net and JS with the demo code provided
I was trying to upgrade Highcharts from v8.2 to 11.4.7. But as I was facing challenges to do that. I was trying to do a simple implementation using the demo code provided in the site.
The .cshtml code is as below

@{var chartOptions = new Highcharts
        {
            Title = new Title
            {
                Text = "Monthly Average Temperature",
                X = -20
            },
            Subtitle = new Subtitle
            {
                Text = "Source: WorldClimate.com",
                X = -20
            },
            XAxis = new List<XAxis>
            {
                new XAxis
                {
                    Categories = new List<string> { "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun",
                                "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec" },

                }
            },
            YAxis = new List<YAxis>
{
                new YAxis
                {
                    Title = new YAxisTitle
                    {
                        Text = "Temperature (°C)"
                    },
                    PlotLines = new List<YAxisPlotLines>
{
                            new YAxisPlotLines
                        {
                            Value = 0,
                            Width = 1,
                            Color = "#808080"
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            Tooltip = new Tooltip
            {
                PointFormat = "{point.y} - {point.custom1} - {point.custom2}"
                //ValueSuffix = "°C"
            },
            Legend = new Legend
            {
                Layout = LegendLayout.Vertical,
                Align = LegendAlign.Right,
                VerticalAlign = LegendVerticalAlign.Middle,
                BorderWidth = 0
            },
            Series = new List<Series>
{
                new LineSeries
                {
                    Name = "Tokyo",
                    Data = @ViewData["tokyoData"] as List<LineSeriesData>
                },
                new LineSeries
                {
                    Name = "NY",
                    Data = @ViewData["nyData"] as List<LineSeriesData>
                },
                new LineSeries
                {
                    Name = "Berlin",
                    Data = @ViewData["berlinData"] as List<LineSeriesData>
                },
                new LineSeries
                {
                    Name = "London",
                    Data = @ViewData["londonData"] as List<LineSeriesData>
                }
            }
        };

        chartOptions.ID = "chart";
        var renderer = new HighchartsRenderer(chartOptions);
    }

    @Html.Raw(renderer.RenderHtml())


and the rendered script looks like
if (document.addEventListener) {document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {createChartchart();});} else if (document.attachEvent) {document.attachEvent("onreadystatechange", function(){if (document.readyState === "complete"){document.detachEvent("onreadystatechange", arguments.callee);createChartchart();}});}function createChartchart() {var ChartOptions = {"tooltip":{"pointFormat":"{point.y} - {point.custom1} - {point.custom2}"},"chart":{"renderTo":"chart"},"series":[{"data":[{"y":7.0},{"y":6.9},{"y":9.5},{"y":14.5},{"y":18.2},{"y":21.5},{"y":25.2},{"y":26.5},{"y":23.3},{"y":18.3},{"y":13.9},{"y":9.6}],"type":"line","name":"Tokyo"},{"data":[{"y":-0.2},{"y":0.8},{"y":5.7},{"y":11.3},{"y":17.0},{"y":22.0},{"y":24.8},{"y":24.1},{"y":20.1},{"y":14.1},{"y":8.6},{"y":2.5}],"type":"line","name":"NY"},{"data":[{"y":-0.9},{"y":0.6},{"y":3.5},{"y":8.4},{"y":13.5},{"y":17.0},{"y":18.6},{"y":17.9},{"y":14.3},{"y":9.0},{"y":3.9},{"y":1.0}],"type":"line","name":"Berlin"},{"data":[{"y":3.9},{"y":4.2},{"y":5.7},{"y":8.5},{"y":11.9},{"y":15.2},{"y":17.0},{"y":16.6},{"y":14.2},{"y":10.3},{"y":6.6},{"y":4.8}],"type":"line","name":"London"}],"yAxis":[{"plotLines":[{"value":0.0,"color":"#808080","width":1.0}],"title":{"text":"Temperature (°C)"}}],"subtitle":{"text":"Source: WorldClimate.com","x":-20.0},"title":{"text":"Monthly Average Temperature","x":-20.0},"xAxis":[{"categories":["Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec"]}],"legend":{"verticalAlign":"middle","layout":"vertical","align":"right","borderWidth":0.0}};Highcharts.chart("chart",ChartOptions);}

This works fine when i load in JSFiddle. But not working in my application. Giving error :
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')
Expected to load the simple chart in browser

Hi Anju, could you share you demo JSFiddle link, so that we can test it. And please also tell us, you are using asp.net mvc or asp.net core mvc.

Hi, what wrapper do you use, is it official Highcharts .NET Standard Wrapper or DotNet.Highcharts?

NuGet\Install-Package Highsoft.Highcharts -Version 11.4.6.4 this is the DLL i am using. But now chart is loading but when trying to style the gridLineDashStyle i am facing issue

Check the related thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78958683/after-highcharts-upgrade-to-latest-version-getting-error-in-setting-dashstyle-pr#comment139227824_78958683
